# Add member to blank struct? c++

Tags: c++, struct

I'd like to add members to a struct after its definition. Any way I can do something like this?

```
struct ss {};
ss.name = ""; //add a string member
ss.age = 0; //add an int member
    
cout << ss.name << "," << ss.age;
```

Comment: You can't.That's not how c++ works. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Moreover, `struct ss = {};` is **not even valid** c++ syntax.

Comment: Hmm, and there isn't reflection either -- The plot of how to c++ thickens! Dun dun dunnnn... I just need to be able to handle some really basic "incoming" JSON, but I didn't really want a robust library.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do it in C++. C++ is a statically typed language. Types are defined in compile time.

But you can use `std::map` to store key value pairs if you like. Something like this will work for you:

```
std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, std::string>> ss;
ss["name"] = std::string("");
ss["age"]  = 0;
std::cout << std::get<std::string>(ss["name"]) << ","
    << std::get<int>(ss["age"]) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oooo I did not know of maps! Thank you, looking more into this option.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way I can do something like this?

No, there is no way to do this in C++. That's not how c++ works. In particular, `struct ss = {};` is **not even valid syntax**.

```
struct ss = {}; // invalid syntax in c++
```

When we provide a definition for struct `ss` say by writing `struct ss{};`, then we're telling the compiler(at compile time) that there aren't any members.

If you want to have members `name` and `age` then you'll have to provide them inside the class definition:

```
struct ss 
{
    std::string name;
    int age = 0; 
};

int main()
{
    ss obj;
    std::cout << obj.name <<std::endl;
    std::cout << obj.age << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: NOT EVEN!! Ok, I see. Chill :'D